# Pegar o max value dentro de um while que está dentro de um cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Minha duvida é a seguinte: tenho meu cursor para a interação linha a linha e dentro dele tenho um `while` para interação horizontal. Estou tentando popular uma tabela cuja PK não possui `identity`, usando o `MAX` e setando o valor +1 dentro do `while`, contudo está estourando erro afirmando que o valor inserido já existe na tabela.

```
DECLARE @RANGE_DE   INT,
            @RANGE_ATE  INT
    declare @MaxId int;
    declare @teste int;
    DECLARE C_REGISTROS CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 
            RANGE_DE,
            RANGE_ATE
        FROM
            #TEMPPARAMETROS

        OPEN C_REGISTROS
        FETCH NEXT FROM C_REGISTROS INTO @RANGE_DE, @RANGE_ATE

        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
        set @teste = (select max(nroproposta) from propadesao);
        set @MaxId = (SELECT MAX(IdPropAdesao) FROM PROPADESAO);
                    while (@RANGE_DE <= @RANGE_ATE)                     
                    begin                                               
                    INSERT INTO  
                    PROPADESAO  
                     (  
                          IdPropAdesao
                         ,IdTpProduto
                         ,IdUnidade  
                         ,DtStatus 
                         ,IdCorretor  
                         ,NroProposta  
                         ,StatusAtual  
                         ,IdMatDivulga                                
                     )
                    SELECT  
                         @MaxId
                         ,IdTpProduto                                     
                         ,1  
                         ,GETDATE()
                         ,IDCORRETOR  
                         ,@teste
                         ,CASE 
                            WHEN IDCORRETOR is null THEN 2
                            WHEN IDCORRETOR IS NOT NULL THEN 3
                          END  
                         ,idcontrato                         
                    FROM  
                         #TEMPPARAMETROS

                        set @range_De += 1
                        SET @MaxId += 1
                        set @teste += 1
                    end
                FETCH NEXT FROM C_REGISTROS INTO @RANGE_DE, @RANGE_ATE
        END
    CLOSE C_REGISTROS
    DEALLOCATE C_REGISTROS
```

Segue o erro :

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 21 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PropAdesao'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PROPADESAO'. The duplicate key value is (5654054). The statement has been terminated. Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 21 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PropAdesao'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PROPADESAO'. The duplicate key value is (5654055).
```

Comment: Olá! Bem-vindo ao SOpt! Poderia informar o erro completo?

Comment: Opa, obrigado meu querido!
Segue o erro :


Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 21
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PropAdesao'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PROPADESAO'. The duplicate key value is (5654054).
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 21
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PropAdesao'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PROPADESAO'. The duplicate key value is (5654055).


E isso se repete por todas as interações do loop.

Comment: Opa! Edite sua pergunta e coloque o erro lá! Acrescente outras informações que achar pertinente e que nos possam te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está ocorrendo, pois é obtido o @MaxId da PROPADESAO e, sem incrementá-lo, é feito um INSERT na PROPADESAO. O incremento é feito só no final do loop. Como o INSERT é feito antes do final do loop, então o SQL Server levanta uma exception de chave primária duplicada.

Troque isso:

```
set @MaxId = (SELECT MAX(IdPropAdesao) FROM PROPADESAO);
```

Por isso:

```
set @MaxId = (SELECT MAX(IdPropAdesao) FROM PROPADESAO) + 1;
```

Faça o mesmo para o @teste:

```
set @teste = (select max(nroproposta) from propadesao) + 1;
```

Comment: essa interação já é feita nessas linhas :

SET MaxId += 1
SET teste += 1

Comment: sim, mas esses incrementos são feitos depois do primeiro Insert. Por isso dá a exceção. Você obtem o MAX e logo depois dá um INSERT, sem incrementar o valor obtido.

Comment: @A.M., você chegou a testar o que estou propondo nessa resposta?